# Credit Card Merchant Names

Tags: finance

I'm looking for databases of credit card merchant names. These are the names that would appear on your credit card bill, such as:

- MICROSOFT*MICROSOFT 36 MSBILL.INFO
- FID BKG SVC LLC MONEYLINE
- AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS AMZN.COM/BILL WA

I feel like they should be freely available somewhere, but they seem to be hard to retrieve at any sort of scale.